python boto3 localstack errors when pulling sqs messages: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version
I am connecting to a localstack sqs from a python script. It's failing with the error "The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.". I am able to run "aws .... sqs receive-message" from command line on the same server and it works fine (no errors). The docker container is running on a EC2 that is in us-east-1b.
From command line
$ aws --endpoint-url http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566  sqs send-message --queue-url http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/sentinus_sqs  --region us-east-1 --message-body 'hello'
{
    "MD5OfMessageBody": "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592", 
    "MessageId": "2dd0065c-b679-6306-dfa3-54b9480ca608"
}
$ aws --endpoint-url http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566 sqs receive-message --queue-url http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/sentinus_sqs --region us-east-1
{
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Body": "hello", 
            "Attributes": {
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1723075186880", 
                "SenderId": "AIDAIT2UOQQY3AUEKVGXU", 
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "2", 
                "SentTimestamp": "1723075177553"
            }, 
            "ReceiptHandle": "khrjpcsmuphwtrnfavrzbhlnvuencioakhchwlkerfoigdppivyvsxqrpzrgxyouyinfbpavoieennjrfbkqhkgbttcycvuxdutocarwtjktxxjgwrvgoxviyvvexubfxjouzayfhymosqydowobvygzigyayesquskejtkcntlmgqaevcuaslaue", 
            "MD5OfBody": "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592", 
            "MessageId": "eaba6691-2245-06bb-b16c-612bd5183b0c"
        }
    ]
}




My python script
AWS_ENDPOINTURL_ENV = os.getenv('AWS_ENDPOINTURL')
AWS_REGION_ENV = os.getenv('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION')
...
sqs = boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url=AWS_ENDPOINTURL_ENV, region_name=AWS_REGION_ENV)
...
response = sqs.receive_message(
                QueueUrl = SQS_URL,
                MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
                WaitTimeSeconds=20
            )
....
for name, value in os.environ.items():
    if "AWS" in name:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))
...
sys.exit(f"ERROR: Unable to connect to SQS: {SQS_URL} {err}")

This is the output
Connecting to SQS : http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/sentinus_sqs
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
AWS_ENDPOINTURL: http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566
ERROR: Unable to connect to SQS: http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/sentinus_sqs An error occurred (404) when calling the ReceiveMessage operation: <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue</Code>
        <Message>The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.</Message>
        <Detail/>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>M6AVX3Z2IV8QO7HII31ZI0KYN3N2E9QQ2TXKASATCORO65WHPWO3</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>


python boto3 sqs.list_queues response output that says no queues.
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '2G8NA3RU82M3RGXNQYXAGQJQMOXOXNPJRB3AH7B05T7CNZG1XONL', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'content-length': '364', 'x-amzn-requestid': '2G8NA3RU82M3RGXNQYXAGQJQMOXOXNPJRB3AH7B05T7CNZG1XONL', 'x-amz-crc32': '3884512511', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH', 'access-control-allow-headers': 'authorization,content-type,content-md5,cache-control,x-amz-content-sha256,x-amz-date,x-amz-security-token,x-amz-user-agent,x-amz-target,x-amz-acl,x-amz-version-id,x-localstack-target,x-amz-tagging', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'x-amz-version-id', 'connection': 'close', 'date': 'Thu, 08 Aug 2024 11:53:50 GMT', 'server': 'hypercorn-h11'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

list-queues from the same cmdline
$aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566  sqs list-queues
{
    "QueueUrls": [
        "http://localhost:4566/000000000000/sentinus_sqs",
        "http://localhost:4566/000000000000/nco_sentinus_sqs"
    ]
}



Upgraded localstack to 3.0.5 and problem is resolved

The message error Unable to connect to SQS: http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/sentinus_sqs An error occurred (404)...<Code>AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue</Code>... means that your queue sentinus_sqs doesn't exist or at least it's not created in region AWS_REGION_ENV us-east-1.
Check it manually with --region in aws cli.

I updated the post. I have two queues sentinus_sqs and nco_sentinus_sqs. I originally had output of nco_sentinus_sqs. I am able to send and pull messages to/from sentinus_sqs from the command line aws command

Which version of localstack are you using ?

can you also add this just befor sqs.receive_message :
response = sqs.list_queues()        if 'QueueUrls' in response:         print("List of SQS Queues:")         for queue_url in response['QueueUrls']:             print(queue_url)     else:         print("No SQS queues found.")

It's showing no queues found. This is what response has
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'VVLXXA1LB6IBDOOD9BU54A10B3J1LD48C1YVSUAQGY3TXKH2B68W', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'content-length': '364', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'VVLXXA1LB6IBDOOD9BU54A10B3J1LD48C1YVSUAQGY3TXKH2B68W', 'x-amz-crc32': '2451911815', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH', 'access-control-allow-headers': 'authorization,content-type,content-md5,cache-control,x-amz-content-sha256,x-a....

Give all the response (what you give is truncated), also which version of localstack are you using ?

Added the output from inside the python script and output from command line to the original post above.

which version of localstack are you using ?

I had 2.0.3. I upgraded to 3.0.5 and the issues seems to have resolved.

voila!! I suspected a bug in version used as I checked the issues of Localstack project and  it seems breaking change was introduced for some versions (issue 2612)
